# Android How to display a file from raw html and javascrip script in a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

My Android app can display files sent as raw HTML in a web view.

Generally there are no issues, but a user is sending the following and all i am getting is a blank white page.

```
 <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head></head>
       <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          window.location.href = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
        </script>
       </body>
   </html>
```

and i cannot get the webview to load the file in the script.

I have all of the following enabled to try to get javascript to work:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

and i have used both of these loadData calls to no avail (not using both at the same time, just included to show what i've tried):

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", documentHtml.htmlRaw, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
webview.loadData(htmlRaw, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

When i create a .html document containing the above html, email it and open it on my Android device, it gives me the choice to use Android HTML Viewer or Chrome/Internet (Android browser)...when i use the HTML Viewer i get the same blank white page that i see in my app...when i use Chrome/Internet it allows me to download the file and then view it.

The file will not always necessarily be a PDF file, but no matter what i want to be able to either:

1. Preferably display the document in the app without having to download it first
2. Download the document to my devices Downloads folder, and then view it.

Any help/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work if you have the urls to the files which you want to display. Just replace `"http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"` this url with the dynamic one.

```
    String html_string = "<div> \n" +
                "<object type=\"text/html\" data=\""+"http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" +"\" width=\"1000px\" height=\"1800px\">\n" +
                "</object>\n" +
                " </div>";
    webView.loadData(html_string, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not in control of what raw HTML is supplied, and i do not want to parse or change the HTML in any way. The HTML in question comes in with a javascript script, my questions is how to work with that HTML.